# Displaying images based upon certain collection

Tags: html, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to find a way to get an image to appear form a collections featured image. I'm able to successfully display an image but unable to access the proper location of the image.

```
{% if template == 'index' %}
{% for frontpage in collections %}
<h2>{{ frontpage.title }} Collection</h2>
      {% if frontpage.image %}
        <a href="collections/{{ frontpage.handle }}"><img src="{{ frontpage.image.src | frontpage_img_url: 'medium' }}" /></a>
      {% else %}
        <img src="{{ frontpage.collections.first.featured_image | product_img_url: 'large' }}" alt="{{ frontpage.title | escape  }}" />
      {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
 {% else %}

{% endif %}
```

The image link appears as **/collections/test-product.png** I need it to appear as **https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0593/8633/collections/test-product_small.png?v=1406487979**. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](http://www.shopify.com.au/technology/5822898-new-collection-image-to-represent-your-collection) on the Shopify wiki gives an example of how to display a collection's featured image:

```
{% if collection.image %}
    {{ collection.image.src | collection_img_url: 'medium' | img_tag: collection.title }}
{% else %}
    {{ collection.products.first.featured_image.src | product_img_url: 'medium' | img_tag: collection.title }}
{% endif %}
```

Also see the docs for [`collection.image`](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/collection#collection-image):

> Returns the collection image. Use the [**collection_img_url**](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/url-filters#collection_img_url) filter to link it to the image file on the Shopify CDN.

And [`collection.image.src`](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/collection#collection-image-src):

> Returns the relative URL to the collection image.

In your code, use `collection_img_url` instead of `frontpage_img_url`.

You should also try `frontpage.products.first.featured_image.src` instead of `frontpage.collections.first.featured_image`.